# Delete some component in ARM template data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to delete some components of data factory in ARM template json file. For an example if I have pipeline A,B,C and I would like to only deploy pipeline A into the data factory. Is there any way to accomplish this? I found only command that delete after deploy but I would prefer to delete it before deploying.

I also consider the option of deleting some of json key and value inside "resource" key in template file. Anyone ever tried this?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the ARM template json file.
Please reference this doc about [Continuous integration lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#continuous-integration-lifecycle).

Please take a look of this post. The other answers (not mine) provided a better answer.
[CI/CD pipeline for Data factory V1 using VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084717/ci-cd-pipeline-for-data-factory-v1-using-vsts)

Comment: Yeah, I thought that microsoft have some command that would select the resource to deploy. Modify ARM template is good approach but when it's like 2000-3000 lines in json, it's not easy. Do you have any recommendation of how to approach this method?

Comment: Currently, there is no such function to select some pipleines. But you could Set up a development data factory with VSTS, then use different branch to control different pipelines. Please reference this doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#continuous-integration-lifecycle